# Is it possible to embed Javascript into Kibana 4.6.1?

Tags: javascript, kibana

What I plan to do is to load a javascript into a predefined dashboard to remove some buttons from the UI.
I want to share a dashboard with my users without having to grant them access to Kibana's indexes and visualization's. Also, I don't want them to change dashboards, they should be rooted to the one I shared with them.

It might sound crazy but one can remove elements using JS.

Comment: [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/scripted-dashboards-.js.html) seems to be **no bueno** for 4.6.1